# Erlang dialyzer from werl.exe?

Tags: command-line, erlang, dialyzer

I tried running `dialyzer --help` from the werl command line and it hung. Am I missing something? Is it only available for the dos shell (I'm on XP SP3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to run dialyzer from within the Erlang shell (and thus, I assume, `werl`) but the way you attempted to invoke it is only appropriate for the DOS shell.

See **Using the Dialyzer from Erlang** near the bottom of http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html

```
1> dialyzer:module_info().
[{exports,[{plain_cl,0},
           {run,1},
           {gui,0},
           {gui,1},
           {plt_info,1},
           {format_warning,1},
           {format_warning,2},
           {module_info,0},
           {module_info,1}]},
 {imports,[]},
 {attributes,[{vsn,[255802808152277240424696594996505155803]}]},
 {compile,[{options,[{outdir,"/private/tmp/homebrew-erlang-R15B01-pQbu/erlang-otp-079e06a/lib/dialyzer/src/../ebin"},
                     warnings_as_errors,warn_missing_spec,warn_untyped_record,
                     warn_unused_import,warn_exported_vars,debug_info]},
           {version,"4.8"},
           {time,{2012,4,13,13,14,35}},
           {source,"/private/tmp/homebrew-erlang-R15B01-pQbu/erlang-otp-079e06a/lib/dialyzer/src/dialyzer.erl"}]}]
2> dialyzer:gui().
ok
```